# PopString and PushString methods in the assembled dll

Tags: nsis

During the execution of the dll the installer crashes on these methods
The methods are taken from the file nsis.pas

```
    function PopString(): string;
var
  th: pstack_t;
begin
  if integer(g_stacktop^) <> 0 then begin
    th := g_stacktop^;
    Result := PChar(@th.text);
    g_stacktop^ := th.next;
    GlobalFree(HGLOBAL(th));
  end;
end;
procedure PushString(const str: string='');
var
  th: pstack_t;
begin
  if integer(g_stacktop) <> 0 then begin
    th := pstack_t(GlobalAlloc(GPTR, SizeOf(stack_t) + g_stringsize));
    lstrcpyn(@th.text, PChar(str), g_stringsize);
    th.next := g_stacktop^;
    g_stacktop^ := th;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ansi or Unicode installer? Ansi or Unicode plug-in?

Comment: Hi 
unicode installer
unicode plugin

Comment: Have you tried to see what the problem is in a debugger?

Comment: I cannot debug the dll

Comment: Why not? Download WinDbg, it is free. Is it push or pop that crashes?

Comment: Спасибо что обяснили как дебажить 
вот что мне выводит windbg:


*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Users\A0F1~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nsd6872.tmp\checklog.dll
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=605dba51 edx=007e8ab0 esi=00436000 edi=007e8ab0
eip=007e8a12 esp=0019d59c ebp=0019d5a4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe cy
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010207
checklog!TMethodImplementationIntercept+0x5e60e:
007e8a12 833800          cmp     dword ptr [eax],0    ds:002b:00000000=????????

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nsis.pas is perhaps not compatible with every Delphi version when compiling as Unicode. You did not specify your version so I don't know if your `string` type is `AnsiString` or `WideString` or `UnicodeString`.

I don't really know Pascal/Delphi anymore but I was able to get it working in FreePascal [with this version](http://nsis.sf.net/temp/Anders/2022/nsis.pas). I'll try to fix it for the next release.

Make sure UNICODE is defined when using this in a Unicode plug-in.

Comment: I use RAD studio 11
as a string 
I use just string 
because in RAD studio (string = UnicodeString)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very easy to solve
It was necessary to call Init() from nsis.pas
and then everything worked